# Basic question about the image and kernel of tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I have a very basic question about the interactions of the image/kernel of module maps with tensor products.

For a ring $A$, $A$-modules $M, M'$ and $N$, and a map of $A$-modules $f: M\mapsto M'$, do the following hold?

$$\operatorname{Im}(f \otimes_A Id_N) = \operatorname{Im}(f) \otimes_A N $$
$$\operatorname{Ker}(f) \otimes_A N \subseteq  \operatorname{Ker}(f \otimes_A Id_N)$$

Comment: Thank you! Is there equality when $f$ is surjective?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for your prompt response!

Comment: my pleasure! happy it helped :)

Comment: hi maroxe; I know this was over 3 years ago, but just for the record, what I wrote in the original answer to this question was completely wrong! in fact, neither of these holds in any sense; I have edited my answer to given examples below to indicate why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** What I had written here before was completely wrong; thanks to FShrike for point this out.

In fact, neither of these is true in any sense; work with $A=\mathbb{Z}$. For the first question, take $M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M'=\mathbb{Q}$, and $f:M\to M'$ the inclusion, and $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $M'\otimes N=0$, so in particular $\mathrm{im}(f\otimes\mathrm{id}_N)=0$, but $\mathrm{im}(f)\otimes N=\mathbb{Z}\otimes N\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For the second question, take $M=\mathbb{Q}$ and $M'=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, with $M\to M'$ the quotient map, and $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $M\otimes N=0$, so in particular $\mathrm{ker}(f\otimes\mathrm{id}_N)=0$, but $\mathrm{ker}(f)\otimes N=\mathbb{Z}\otimes N\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: it is not correct that the natural map $\ker(f)\otimes M\to\ker(f\otimes1)$ is injective; it is not the case that $\ker(f)\otimes M$ is naturally a submodule of $\ker(f\otimes1)$.

Comment: @FShrike oh dear, thanks very much for pointing this out!! was clearly not thinking clearly at the time. it is now corrected :)